# Why the JPanel Graphics2D drawing appers above the scroll bar?

Tags: jpanel, drawing, polygon, scrollpane

Why the JPanel Graphics2D drawing appers above the scroll bar?

I tried to solve this issue but I couldn't succeed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JArmP.png)

I tried validate() and repaint() with jpanel also with JScrollPane but it did not work.